# Is there any software to aid in planning code structure?

Tags: programming, planning

I'm attempting to plan out (programming) how various classes would interact, what they would encapsulate and overall flow of my code structure. I am hoping to do this in random spare moments on my android phone, but I am open to PC software as well.

Ideally, I imagine this similar to a mind-mapping. However, pure mind-mapping software (that I have found anyway) could have many improvements to make it more suitable for code structuring. One thing that would be nice is a good representation of encapsulation, mind-maps generally only allow connections and dont really allow for the idea that one bubble would contain other bubbles, and it can easily become a mess of connections when classes start getting used within other classes.

I try to find this type of software on google, but I must be failing to use the correct terms.

Comment: Try 1) Read Up on UML & 2) Search for UML diagramming software.

Comment: Good comparison of UML tools at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools